# How to response ajax?

Tags: atk4

I've got field which makes ajax request on user input, and I want to response to it with json object. I use jQuery function `$.getJSON` with url `?page=answersearch`, but it doesn't work. Instead of answering with json type data, it sends text/html type data. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting a string of text back from an AJAX request, regardless of the declared MIME-type, you may make use of jQuery's $.parseJSON function.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/someurl',
    type: 'get',
    data: {
        page: 'answersearch'
    },
    success: function(rsp) {
        if (typeof rsp === 'string') {
            rsp = $.parseJSON(rsp);
        }
        // rsp has been changed from a string into an object.
    }
});
```

Also, on the server side, you may wish to set the Content-Type header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/json')
```

It's not 100% necessary, however.

Comment: The problem is that server side sends whole page html stuff, not just my json object. I don't know how use frontend(I need it) without sending to browser layout, just json object.

Comment: Try exiting after you manually print the json data: `echo json_encode($response_json_object);header('Content-Type: text/json');exit;`

Comment: Agile Toolkit has this concept of evaluating AJAX, but it shouldn't stop you from using the JSON like @benastan suggested. http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/js